# Error deploying mdb

Tags: java, jboss, ejb

Can anyone help me with this. Currently i am trying to do a JMS application. Tried to test whether the server is running properly with the project. But this happen ::

> 14:51:54,603 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (management-handler-thread - 10) JBAS014612: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "FirstMDBProject.jar")]): java.util.NoSuchElementException: No child 'runtime-name' exists
>       at org.jboss.dmr.ModelValue.requireChild(ModelValue.java:362) [jboss-dmr-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
>       at org.jboss.dmr.ObjectModelValue.requireChild(ObjectModelValue.java:298) [jboss-dmr-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
>       at org.jboss.dmr.ModelNode.require(ModelNode.java:812) [jboss-dmr-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
>       at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentDeployHandler.execute(DeploymentDeployHandler.java:71)
>       at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:397) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.3.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.1.3.Final-redhat-4]
>       at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.doCompleteStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:284) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.3.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.1.3.Final-redhat-4]
>       at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.completeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:211) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.3.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.1.3.Final-redhat-4]
>       at org.jboss.as.controller.CompositeOperationHandler.execute(CompositeOperationHandler.java:85) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.3.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.1.3.Final-redhat-4]
>       at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:397) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.3.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.1.3.Final-redhat-4]
>       at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.doCompleteStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:284) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.3.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.1.3.Final-redhat-4]
>       at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.completeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:211) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.3.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.1.3.Final-redhat-4]
>       at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl$DefaultPrepareStepHandler.execute(ModelControllerImpl.java:473) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.3.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.1.3.Final-redhat-4]
>       at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:397) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.3.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.1.3.Final-redhat-4]
>       at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.doCompleteStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:284) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.3.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.1.3.Final-redhat-4]
>       at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.completeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:211) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.3.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.1.3.Final-redhat-4]
>       at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.internalExecute(ModelControllerImpl.java:126) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.3.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.1.3.Final-redhat-4]
>       at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.execute(ModelControllerImpl.java:111) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.3.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.1.3.Final-redhat-4]
>       at org.jboss.as.controller.remote.ModelControllerClientOperationHandler$ExecuteRequestHandler.doExecute(ModelControllerClientOperationHandler.java:139) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.3.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.1.3.Final-redhat-4]
>       at org.jboss.as.controller.remote.ModelControllerClientOperationHandler$ExecuteRequestHandler$1.execute(ModelControllerClientOperationHandler.java:108) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.3.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.1.3.Final-redhat-4]
>       at org.jboss.as.protocol.mgmt.AbstractMessageHandler$2$1.doExecute(AbstractMessageHandler.java:296) [jboss-as-protocol-7.1.3.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.1.3.Final-redhat-4]
>       at org.jboss.as.protocol.mgmt.AbstractMessageHandler$AsyncTaskRunner.run(AbstractMessageHandler.java:518) [jboss-as-protocol-7.1.3.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.1.3.Final-redhat-4]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [rt.jar:1.6.0_25]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [rt.jar:1.6.0_25]
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_25]
>       at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122) [jboss-threads-2.0.0.GA-redhat-2.jar:2.0.0.GA-redhat-2]

Please anyone? What should i do to get through this?

Comment: You did not provide any information. How do you configure the mdb? How is the jms endpoint configured for the server? etc..

Comment: Actually, im trying to create a jms program based on the code that i found on the internet. Am really new to this. This is the page that i reffered to: http://theopentutorials.com/examples/java-ee/ejb3/how-to-create-ejb3-mdb-queue-project-in-eclipse-jboss-6-1/. Followed all the steps in order but there is still error.